# Asymptotic run time complexity of an expression

Tags: algorithm, math, mathematical-optimization, polynomial-math, asymptotic-complexity

Can I say that:

log n + log (n-1) + log (n-2) + .... + log (n - k) = theta(k * log n)?

Formal way to write the above:

Sigma (i runs from 0 to k) log (n-i) = theta (k* log n)?

If the above statement is right, how can I prove it?

If it is wrong, how can I express it (the left side of the equation, of course) as an asymptotic run time function of n and k?

Thanks.

Comment: How have you been proving theta bounds before?

Comment: @DennisMeng - a little bit, but I need this one especially.

Comment: I said "how have" not "have."

Comment: @DennisMeng oh, I don't have a great experience as a "theta bounds solver". In the course I'm taking right now, there is no emphasis of theta bounds, although we need them a little bit.

Comment: Just wondering. The usual approach I've seen is to prove big-O and big-Omega bounds, but if you're still only just getting your feet wet, then I can understand being unfamiliar with proof methods.

Answer (score 2):

Denote:

`LHS = log(n) + log(n-1) + ... + log(n-k)`

`RHS = k * log n`

Note that:

`LHS = log(n*(n-1)*...*(n-k)) = log(polynomial of (k+1)th order)`

It follows that this is equal to:

`(k+1)*log(n(1 + terms that are 0 in limit))`

If we consider a division:

`(k+1)*log(n(1 + terms that are 0 in limit)) / RHS`

we get in limit:

`(k+1)/k = 1 + 1/k`

So if  `k` is a constant, both terms grow equally fast. So `LHS = theta(RHS)`.

[Wolfram Alpha seems to agree.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28%28k%2B1%29%2Alog%28n%2A%281+%2B+1%2F%28n%5E2%29+%2B+1%2F%28n%5E3%29+%2B+1%2F%28n%5E4%29+%2B+...+%2B+1%2F%28n%5Ek%29%29%29%29+%2F+%28k%2Alog%28n%29%29%2C+n+-%3E+infinity)

When `n` is constant, terms that previously were `0` in limit don't disappear but instead you get:

`(k+1) * some constant number / k * (some other constant number)`

So it's:

`(1 + 1/k)*(another constant number)`. So also `LHS = theta(RHS)`.

Comment: I need an explicit theta expression, are you saying that this is theta(lg (n^(k+1))?

Comment: Thank you very much! Can I say that generally log (polynomial of kth order) = tetha(k*log n)?

Comment: @Programmer As I see it now - yes. But I'd be very careful, limits can be very counter intuitive ;) But it's easy to experiment with WolframAlpha.

Comment: Thank you very much :) The course I'm taking is about algorithms, so the mathematical layer isn't so important.

Comment: In you answer you are saying that log (polynomial of k+1 order) = theta(k*log n), while in you comment you said that log(polynomial k order) = theta(k*log n) - is that make sense?

Comment: @Programmer Regarding your question: why don't you just check this for yourself, this is trivial. Substitute `k` instead of `k+1` in my derivation, or change it in WolframAlpha input I provided so you'll notice it doesn't matter.

Comment: I tried to notify you with the @ sign in the second comment, but I didn't succeed (I'm new in Stackoverflow).

Answer (score 2):

When proving `Θ`, you want to prove `O` and `Ω`.

Upper bound is proven easily:
`log(n(n-1)...(n-k)) ≤ log(n^k) = k log n = O(k log n)`

For the lower bound, if `k ≥ n/2`,
then in the product there is `n/2` terms greater than `n/2`:
`log(n(n-1)...(n-k)) ≥ (n/2)log(n/2) = Ω(n log n) ≥ Ω(k log n)`

and if `k ≤ n/2`, all terms are greater than `n/2`:
`log(n(n-1)...(n-k)) ≥ log((n/2)^k) = k log(n/2) = Ω(k log n)`

Comment: Why log (n*(n-1)*...*(n-k) <= log (n^k)? I mean, notice that the degree of polynomial n*(n-1)*...*(n-k) is (k+1), not k - does it matter?

Comment: You're right, it should  have been `log(n^(k+1))`, but that's not a problem since this still fits in `O(k log n)`. Same thing in the last line, should be `log((n/2)^(k+1))`, but also doesn't really change anything.